# How to create small exe in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, demoscene

I need to create exe file smaller that 64KB.
In previous project I was able to do 4KB by using crinkler and not using any classes or std library.
I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

In my current project I'm using classes a lot, but I would like to use crinkler.
I'm getting errors like that one

> Error 1   error LNK: Cannot find symbol '??3@YAXPAX@Z'

I was searching Google for solution. [Here](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=18158&howmanycomments=25&page=5) somebody wrote to don't use std, but I'm not using anything from namespace std.

Is there a special way to make it work with classes?

Comment: have you tried other tools like http://upx.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: `??3@YAXPAX@Z` translates to `void __cdecl operator delete(void *)`. Are you linking with the appropriate CRT?

Comment: Yes. I was trying upx. After using upx my intro have about 100KB, it's still to much.
I have lot of unused code. Clinker can detect and remove unused code. Upx seem to not doing it.

Comment: I'm linking with /MT. I was also trying to link with /MD, but the result was the same.

Comment: You do have libctiny set up, I hope?

Comment: I didn't. Now when I'm trying to do so, but I have unsolved functions.
sin, cos, etc I can define by my self (I prefer if I don't have to).
But there is a problem with wWinMain. If I define my main function as wWinMain, then I got error that _wWinMainCRTStartup is not defined.
If I define my main function as _wWinMainCRTStartup then wWinMain is undefined. Therefore I think that LIBCTINY is only for command line applications.

Comment: An older version of Visual Studio should generate smaller files. Of course you should compile it in Release mode too. There are many project properties you can adjust to reduce the file size, but right now I don't remember exactly.

Comment: It is old topic now.

Comment: The solution for my problem was to compile project with option "/MT" and use Mew11 to compress it.